# database.open No intellisense

Tags: asp.net, database, razor

I'm trying to open a database (using vb) using database.open but there is no Intellisense for this. What do I need to do to open a database? All of the examples I can find show database.open("ConnectionString") but this option isn't available to me.

I'm with with a fresh ASP.NET Razor application (not MVC) and have a web.config reference to a suitable database.

Comment: *Where* are you typing `database.Open("ConnectionString")`?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about complete ado.net basics? If you are, check this site out: [using ado.net with VB.Net and C#](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4278/using-adonet-with-sql-server/)

You actually want to create the object for the sql connection before you open the connection:

```
Dim sqlConn as new SqlConnection("ConnectionString")
sqlConn.Open()
```

Also, in your web project, you need to add the reference System.Data (this should add System.Data.SqlClient) and this will need to be imported using

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

at the top of the page before the class.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but the answer doesn't relate to ASP.NET Razor.